# Reducer: Returns Default state

Tags: typescript, redux

I am new to redux and trying to understand how redux works, I have made a small application of counter which increments the value everytime
Here is the code of store.ts file:

```
import { iAppState } from './store';
import { INCREMENT } from './actions';
export interface iAppState {
    counter: number
};

export const INITIAL_STATE = {
    counter: 0
}

export function rootReducer(state: iAppState, action): iAppState {
    switch(action.type) {
        case INCREMENT : return {counter: state.counter + 1}
    }
    return state;
}
```

When i comment the `return state` line and use `console.log(ngRedux.getState());` it returns Nan of type as number, But when i uncomment the same line it displays the correct value.

What is happening internally?

Answer (score 0):

When redux is first initialized in your application, an action type of `@@INIT` is usually dispatched on start up.

By commenting out the `return state;` line at the end of your reducer, this causes the `@@INIT` action to return `undefined`. That causes the "next state" of your application after `@@INIT` to be `undefined`.

This in turn means that dispatching the `INCREMENT` action causes your reducer to perform arithmetic on an undefined `counter`, which will result in the NaN you're currently getting.

Consider also, initializing your reducers state by making the following alteration:

```
export function rootReducer(state: iAppState = INITIAL_STATE, action): iAppState {
    switch(action.type) {
        case INCREMENT : return {counter: state.counter + 1}
    }
    return state;
}
```